# Mint desktop broken after update

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I am running `Linux Mint 14` with `Cinnamon` desktop environment. After automatically applying upgrades from update manager and restarting the system, Cinnamon UI is broken. Unfortunately I don't remember which files were upgraded.

All windows lost their title bars and also the lower menu bar is gone and it doesn't activate on mouse hover. The glxgears program is working so I assume that OpenGL is fine. Is there any way I can revert to the state of my machine before my last click that did the upgrades?

Comment: What is your graphic card, did you have any proprietary graphics driver installed? Have you tested your system how it works with default nouveau driver?